# making a list item result VICEVERSA

Tags: c#

this is my action :

```
public ActionResult List()
        {
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var list = new List<ArchiveViewModel>();
            for (var startDate = new DateTime(2012, 11, 1); startDate <= currentDate; startDate = startDate.AddMonths(1))
            {
                list.Add(new ArchiveViewModel
                {
                    Month = startDate.Month,
                    Year = startDate.Year,
                    FormattedDate = startDate.ToString("MMMM, yyyy")
                });
            }
            return View("List",list);
        }
```

and this is the View

```
@model IList<Blog.Web.UI.ViewModels.ArchiveViewModel>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

            @Html.ActionLink(item.FormattedDate, "Post", "Archive", new { month = item.Month, year = item.Year }, null)

    }
```

output of this action result is like this

```
November, 2012
December, 2012
January, 2013
February, 2013
March, 2013
April, 2013
May, 2013
June, 2013
```

but I want to have in output something like this

```
  June, 2013
   May, 2013
  April, 2013
 March, 2013
...
November, 2012
```

how can I do that ??

Comment: How did you get this error? **can not assign void to local variable!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the list backwards.  You can sort it in either way as described by others, or you can do it right the first time.

```
public ActionResult List()
        {
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            var list = new List<ArchiveViewModel>();
            for (var startDate = currentDate; startDate >= new DateTime(2012, 11, 1); startDate = startDate.AddMonths(-1))
            {
                list.Add(new ArchiveViewModel
                {
                    Month = startDate.Month,
                    Year = startDate.Year,
                    FormattedDate = startDate.ToString("MMMM, yyyy")
                });
            }
            return View("List",list);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var newList = list.Reverse(); //This will change the order of all records
```

or

```
var newList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Year)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.Month)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Although both answers (@Nnp) solve the problem, this one is more clear about the intent, and helps with code readability.

Answer (score 0):

var newList  = list.Reverse();

Comment: can not assign void to local variable !